# how can i process the multiprocess program result in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

For example, in python language, if I start multiple subprocess

```
def f(idx):
    #process data and generate files
    fi = open("test_%idx.txt"%idx, "a")
    fi.write(idx)
    fi.close()

for i in range(5):
    p = subprocess.Popen(f, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate(b' i')
```

After the subprocess, How can I process the generated file by f function in main process or in every separate process?

Thank you in advance.